# How do I convert an existent JavaScriptObject to a java primitive type in GWT?

Tags: gwt

Supposing that I have a reference to an existent JavaScriptObject that holds a primitive type, like an int value, how can I get this int value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [JSNI](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2008/07/getting-to-really-know-gwt-part-1-jsni.html) functionality to "adapt" between GWT's Java and underlying Javascript: more specifically, use the `cast()` method to adapt to the desired type. You can afterwards "repackage" the object to any Java primitive you want/can.

You might need to write a `native` method on a sub-class of JavascriptObject in order to "reach" the primitive type you are referring to. See [this article](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2008/08/getting-to-really-know-gwt-part-2.html) for more details.